# How would I handle domain whitelisting?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to find out how would I handle whitelisting certain domain names. If the request originates from a particular subdomain, such as `<id>.domain-name.com`, access to the images will be restricted to a whitelist of approved domains. Requests from domains not on the whitelist will result in a 403 error.

I'm not sure what should I be doing exactly ? Do I use `map` context ?

for example, my nginx.conf would look something like this

```
map $http_host $whitelist {
  default 0;
  "~^(?<id>\w+)\.domain-name\.example\.com$" $id;

  # whitelist domains
  whitelist1 1;
  whitelist2 1;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  proxy_intercept_errors on;

  error_page 400 = @fallback;

  if ($whitelist = 0) {
    return 403;
  }

  proxy_pass $whitelist;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to prevent image hotlinking in nginx?](https://serverfault.com/questions/907807/how-to-prevent-image-hotlinking-in-nginx)

Comment: [How do I add Access-Control-Allow-Origin in NGINX](https://serverfault.com/questions/162429/how-do-i-add-access-control-allow-origin-in-nginx?rq=1) could also a good choice

Answer (score 0):

Your `nginx` configuration looks mostly correct, but there are a few changes that you can make to ensure that it works as expected.

First, you need to define the actual whitelist of domains that are allowed to access the images. In your current configuration, you have defined two whitelisted domains as `whitelist1` and `whitelist2`. You should replace these with the actual domain names that are allowed to access the images.

Second, in your map context, you have defined the variable `$whitelist` as the value of the subdomain that is making the request. However, what you actually need is the value of the domain name that is making the request, without the subdomain. You can modify your map context to extract the domain name as follows:

```
map $http_host $whitelist {
  default 0;
  "~^(?<subdomain>\w+)\.(?<domain>domain-name\.example\.com)$" $domain;

  # whitelist domains
  whitelist1 example.com;
  whitelist2 subdomain.example.com;
}
```

In the example above, the regular expression captures the subdomain and the domain name separately. The variable `$domain` is then set to the value of the domain name without the subdomain.

Finally, you can use the `$whitelist` variable in your server block to determine whether to allow or deny access to the images. Your updated configuration would look like this:

```
map $http_host $whitelist {
  default 0;
  "~^(?<subdomain>\w+)\.(?<domain>domain-name\.example\.com)$" $domain;

  # whitelist domains
  whitelist1 example.com;
  whitelist2 subdomain.example.com;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  proxy_intercept_errors on;

  error_page 400 = @fallback;

  if ($whitelist = 0) {
    return 403;
  }

  location /images {
    # allow access only to whitelisted domains
    allow $whitelist;
    deny all;

    # serve images from disk
    alias /path/to/images;
  }

  location @fallback {
    # handle errors
    return 400;
  }
}
```