# Prevent hot link nginx specific domain page

Tags: nginx, hotlinking

I have the following code on nginx to prevent hotlink

```
location ~ ^/(.*\.(jpe?g|png|gif))$ {
    valid_referers none blocked domain1.ext *.domain2.ext *.domain3.ext;
    if ($invalid_referer) {
        return 403;
    }
}
```

domain1 and domain2 are mine so no issue.
Domain 3 is not mine and I need allow refer only from a specific page.
I mean I don't wanna allow the full domain3.ext but only a specific page who is: `status.domain3.ext/codepage-100`

Can I edit the code above to replace domain3.ext with `status.domain3.ext/codepage-100`?

I tried:

```
location ~ ^/(.*\.(jpe?g|png|gif))$ {
    valid_referers none blocked domain1.ext *.domain2.ext status.domain3.ext/codepage-100;
    if ($invalid_referer) {
        return 403;
    }
}
```

but is not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to prevent image hotlinking in nginx?](https://serverfault.com/questions/907807/how-to-prevent-image-hotlinking-in-nginx)

Comment: This seems not helping me to allow a specific URL page. The example show only domain whitelist not specific URL.